# Keras can't use callback to store checkpoint

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

```
train_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_set = train_data.flow_from_directory('train_set',
                                           target_size=(28,28),
                                           batch_size=16,
                                           class_mode='categorical')
test_set = train_data.flow_from_directory('test_set',
                                           target_size=(28,28),
                                           batch_size = 16,
                                           class_mode='categorical')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weight.hdf5",
                               monitor='val_acc',
                               verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True)
history = classifier.fit_generator(train_set,
                                   steps_per_epoch=210,
                                   epochs=5,
                                   callbacks=[checkpointer],
                                   validation_data=test_set,
                                   validation_steps=90)

classifier.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5')
```

When I tried to load the best weights, it shows no such file or directory. How should I make a change? Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the filename; you save at

```
filepath="best_weight.hdf5"
```

while you try to load `'best_weights.hdf5'`.

Remove the final `s` from the file name, i.e.:

```
classifier.load_weights('best_weight.hdf5')
```